# Write a log of compilation errors on a file - Fortran 77

Tags: fortran, fortran77, intel-parallel-studio

I am not a big expert with Fortran. I am compiling a code using Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015. I get so many errors and I would like to save them to a file in order to look at them easily.

I use "ifort code.for /4R8" for compiling.

Is there any possible way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

```
ifort code.for /4R8 > log.txt 2>&1
```

or

```
ifort code.for /4R8 2> log.txt
```

More info [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot... it worked. Both of them gave me the a repost of error in the log file.